# "How do I display the cout<<"Fever"; because I am not familiar with string array and it is stuck at the selection part also?

Tags: c++

```
string sick[5] = { "FEVER","FLUE","FOOD POISONING" };

for (int r = 0; r < 5; r++)
{
    if(sick[r].compare("FEVER") == 0)
    {
        found = true;
        cout << "Fever";
    }
}
```

Comment: *"it make me stuck at the selection part also?"* What selection part? Please post the whole program and not just a snippet. From the part that you posted I can't see the error, if I run that it does print `"Fever"` for me (after adding a `main` function and declaring `found`, of course).

Comment: Did you mean `"FLUE"` (duct for smoke) or `"FLU"` (influenza)?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `operator==` and output directly with a new-line, something like:

```
if (sick[r] == "FEVER")
{
    found = true;
    cout << sick[r] << '\n';
}
```